# How to trigger binding of select based on the changed value in another select?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say that I have list of countries and each country has a list of states/regions. So there are two selects. First to select country, and when country changes I want to trigger binding of the states select. How do you link these two controls to trigger binding of the states select when country changes?

```
<select id="countries" 
data-ng-model="vm.permanentAddress.countryCode"
   data-ng-options="country.code for country in vm.form.countries">
  </select>

<select data-ng-model="vm.permanentAddress.stateCode" 
    data-ng-options="state.value for state in vm.getStatesForCountry(vm.permamentAddress.countryCode)">
</select>
```

UPDATE:
I was probably not explicit in my question as to what I want to do. I do not want to create any new properties that are then watched by angular for a change. I just want to tell anuglar, hey something has changed, go ahead and re-evaluate the binding for this control.

Is it not possible?

Comment: Can you make a plnkr or something?  What are you trying to bind in the other select when the country changes?  And what do you mean by "bind"?  Do you mean set the model `vm.permanentAddress.stateCode`?

Comment: @ErikDonohoo: What I am trying is to get the list of the states populated based on the selection in the country select. So If one selects USA, then state select would have a list of all states. Question is how to trigger that.

Comment: I will make a plnkr for you

Answer (score 0):

In your controller have something like this:

```
$scope.setStateOptions = function(country){

  $scope.stateOptions = /* whatever code you use to get the states */

}
```

Then your html can be:

```
<select id="countries" 
   data-ng-model="vm.permanentAddress.countryCode"
   data-ng-options="country.code for country in vm.form.countries"
   data-ng-change="setStateOptions(country)">
  </select>

<select 
    data-ng-model="vm.permanentAddress.stateCode" 
    data-ng-options="state.value for state in stateOptions">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use the jquery chanied select plugin:
http://jquery-plugins.net/chained-selects-jquery-plugin

I have used it for 4 select list chained and it worked fine.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9JImidwBgX7pxwAbqugz?p=preview).  You just need to use the ng-change to change the model you have set for the states

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the dynamic nature of JavaScript to bind the key from the first list to the second list. Then you only have to set a default value on the change. If you remove the `$watch` it will still work, the second `select` will just default to empty when you switch the category.

Here's my data set-up and watch:

```
app.controller("myController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = ['shapes', 'colors', 'sizes'];
    $scope.data.shapes = ['square', 'circle', 'ellipse'];
    $scope.data.colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
    $scope.data.sizes = ['small', 'medium', 'large'];       
    $scope.category = 'colors'; 
    $scope.$watch('category', function () {
        $scope.item = $scope.data[$scope.category][0];
    });
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <select id="categories" 
    data-ng-model="category"        
    data-ng-options="category for category in data"></select>
    <select id="item"         
    data-ng-model="item"         
    data-ng-options="item for item in data[category]"></select>
    {{category}}: {{item}}</div>
```

You can, of course, change this to host complex objects and use keys or other identifiers to switch between the lists. The full fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/8QDNv/